# Rewrite URL to remap WordPress Permalink

Tags: url-rewriting, apache, linux

I'm moving my WordPress site to a new host, and in the process I want to make a one time change to the Permalinks. I want to rewrite the URLs from `/2015/11/sample-post/` to `/sample-post/` but how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way to accomplish this would be to change the structure to `/%postname%/` and add a 301 redirect to your .htaccess file for the old structure:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ http://example.com/$3
```

Change `example.com` to your domain and add the redirect above the `# BEGIN WordPress` directive so it won't be removed if WordPress updates the file.

EDIT- redirect /yyyy/mm/dd/postname

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ http://example.com/$4
```

Comment: Again, We are trying to preserve the old URL of /2015/11/sample-post/ for SEO purposes because those are indexed by search engines, hence I don't want to change the permalink structure in the WP on the referring site. In fact, the WP on referring server will be offline and delete and need to implement this in RewriteRule preserving old URL structure.

Comment: This will preserve SEO by telling the search bots that the content has been permanently moved to the new structure. [This is the method that Google recommends](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en).

Comment: I think I want a way to do this without relying on an instance of WordPress up and running on the referring server.  I don't see how changing the permalink in WP will not affect the user experience, it needs a seamless redirect to the new URL structure.   Am I missing something?

Comment: The RedirectMatch works to redirect referringserver.com to newserver.com but doesn't redirect URLs as I want them to, such as: referringserver.com/2015/11/post to newserver.com/post

Comment: So your domain name is also changing?

Comment: Yes domain name is also changing.

Comment: You don't need an instance of WordPress on the old server to redirect, but you do need some way to receive requests at your old domain and redirect them to the new one. The rule above does what you want with redirecting old structure to new structure, it takes `/nnnn/nn/something/` and 301 redirects it to `/something/`.

Comment: I am trying and really hope the RedirectMatch works.   I've tried RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(?!2015/11/)(.+)$ http://www.newserver.com/$3 but it's not going to /something/ like you said it would and throwing a 404 error.

Comment: That rule doesn't match what I have above, you should only change `example.com`. I suggest using Google Search Console to guide you through the process. It has a number of tools to help you do this correctly.

Comment: I tried it both ways, only replacing example.com and still the same result.

Comment: ahhh, cleared browser cache, in Chrome, I think its working!  :)

Comment: Is there a minor variation to remap URLs from /yyyy/mm/post successfully but now trying to modify that to redirect using the pattern match of /yyyy/mm/dd/post using this same RedirectMatch?

Comment: See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Go-to `settings -> permalink`.  and than  add it like this: `%post_name%`.

Comment: You misunderstand.  On the referring server, I want it to send my new server traffic with hostname.com/sample-post not hostname.com/2015/11/sample-post

Comment: That's what I am also said.  Try this before try this one.  Take a back up of the existing code and try this.  It will solve your problem

Comment: We are trying to preserve the old URL of /2015/11/sample-post/ for SEO purposes because those are indexed by search engines, hence I don't want to change the permalink structure in the WP on the referring site.  In fact, the WP on referring server will be offline and delete and need to implement this in RewriteRule preserving old URL structure.