# Wordpress 4.4 old permalink redirect

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess

i have a question for you and i hope you can help me out.

I have a site with over 500 broken links due to an old permalink i changed 3 year ago.
I know i could use a plugin for that (if you recommend one that works well today, feel free to name it as well) but i would like to do it myself if it's possible (i want to learn how to do it, plus as i've read, using .htaccess would be faster to load) i've read a lot of tutorials and Stack Overflow threads about it and i think i almost have it but i still need a little bit more info:

My old permalink was: /year/month/postname (i.e 2012/01/postname , 2012/03/postname, etc)

and now it's just /postname

What would be the best way to do so? i mean i could create the rules one by one (one for 2012/01, one for 2012/02 and so on), but i was thinking maybe wordpress has a better way, a more generalized way to achieve the same thing with less rules, and i was wondering if you know it, or if you could point out a link or something (i wouldn't even know how to start searching)

thanks in advance!

Comment: [See this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208766/4771).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite URL to remap WordPress Permalink](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208761/rewrite-url-to-remap-wordpress-permalink)